# How do you adjust sample weights in two steps without replacement

Tags: math, sampling

Say, you have a vector of probabilities `p` and want to sample an index from `p`. However, we don't want to sample from `p` directly, but rather sample a subset of indices first and subsequently select from this subset. My problem is: how do I sample with the correct weights?

For simplicity, let's assume `p = [1/6, 1/3, 1/2]`. We first sample 2 indices from `p` to obtain a subset `I`. `I` can be `[0, 1]` (probability `1/15 + 1/12 = 3/20`), `[0, 2]` (probability `1/10 + 1/6 = 4/15`), or `[1, 2]` (probability `1/4 + 1/3 = 7/12`). The problem is, I have no idea how to attach probabilities on the second sampling step.

Assume `I = [0, 1]`, it would be intuitive to sample with weights `[1/3, 2/3]`, however, this strategy causes undersampling of low probabilities (for the first index, we get `3/20 * 1/3 + 4/15 * 1/4 = 7/60 < 1/6`).

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: `1/15 + 1/12 = 3/20` what are those fractions?

Comment: `1/15 = ` probability for sampling index 0, then sampling index 1. `1/12 =` probability for sampling index 1, then index 0. Hence, `3/20 = ` probability of obtaining the set `[0, 1]`.

Comment: Interesting question, however, it's more suitable for math.stackexchange.com or stats.se. That said, it sounds like what you want to do is select a subset with probability P = (sum of individual p's), and then, to sample from the subset, select an single element with probability p/P (i.e. normalize the p's in the subset so they sum to 1). I'm not sure I understand what you want to do, though.